# Get Wordpress post title in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to have Wordpress post title in array.

I have my post titles in my custom post type as names of people with their surnames. I want to display my posts based alphabetically on their surnames and store it in an array. How do I do this in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the posts for your custom post type using `WP_Query`, and then run through each of them to get the titles.

```
// just get IDs rather than whole post object - more efficient
// as you only require the title
$post_ids = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type_name', // replace with CPT name
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'surname_field_name' // replace with custom field name
));

$post_titles = array();

// go through each of the retrieved ids and get the title
if ($post_ids->have_posts()):
    foreach( $post_ids->posts as $id ):
        // get the post title, and apply any filters which plugins may have added
        // (get_the_title returns unfiltered value)
        $post_titles[] = apply_filters('the_title', get_the_title($id));
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Using `WP_Query` has the benefit that it does not alter the main loop on your page, and you can get the posts in the order that your require by using `orderby` along with the name of the custom field which contains the surname.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an array outside the loop, then get the array filled up with the names, than sort the array.

```
<?php
// the array for the names
$name_array = array();

if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        $name_array[] = $post->title;
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
    if ( sizeof( $name_array ) > 0 ) {
      sort( $name_array );
    } // end if for sizeof()
} // end if
?>
```

If you cannot create the array outside The Loop, than you may move it under **if ( have_posts() ) {**.

Important note: this solution only contains the names in your current loop, so if your query does not hold all the posts, or is offset / paged, etc. then the array will not get all the names you have in your custom post type. If you would like to have all the names in the array and your loop query does not hold all the posts, then you have to query again - just for the titles (names).